# Error E405 while trying to install discord.js with npm

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, software-installation, node.js

I'm trying to host a Discord bot in my RPI3B+, but the required node.js package **discord.js** always fails to install. I've tried purging both NPM and Node.js, and i have upgraded my Raspbian using `sudo apt-get update`.

This is a screenshot of the error:
[image: discord.js npm install throws error E405]

I'm running Raspian 9 Stretch, and [here is the npm debug log file.](https://pastebin.com/QY01AJpj)

Comment: You may get more support by filing an issue at http://github.com/npm/npm/issues. Make sure to give them that debug log.

Comment: It says "This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only. ". Is there somewherre else wwhere i can open a ticket?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.